# How to display trending clips for the entire week, instead of the day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application that tracks each clips view count and by doing so we're able to display the trending clips for the day. However, since the user-base is still relatively small we'd like to display the trending clips of the week.

Here's our current code:

```
# trending slider
    today_clips = Clip.joins(:clip_views).where(clip_views: {viewed_at: Date.today}).keep_if{|c| (c.film.active)}.uniq.map{|c| [c.id, c.clip_views.count]}
    ordered_clips = today_clips.sort {|a, b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
    @trending_clips = []
    if ordered_clips.present?
      ordered_clips.map{|a| a[0]}.each do |i|
        @trending_clips << Clip.find(i)
      end
      @trending_clips.keep_if{|c| (c.film.active)}
    end
```

How might I change the above code to display trending clips for the entire week, instead of resetting each day?

Thanks!

Comment: Can i suggest you submit this snippet of code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ It definitely needs some love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing in the range you want into your where clause:

```
weekly_clips = Clip.joins(:clip_views)
                   .where(clip_views: {viewed_at: 1.week.ago..Date.today})
                   .keep_if{|c| (c.film.active)}
                   .uniq
                   .map{|c| [c.id, c.clip_views.count]}
ordered_clips = weekly_clips.sort {|a, b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
@trending_clips = []
if ordered_clips.present?
  ordered_clips.map{|a| a[0]}.each do |i|
    @trending_clips << Clip.find(i)
  end
  @trending_clips.keep_if{|c| (c.film.active)}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change

```
.where(clip_views: {viewed_at: Date.today})
# => WHERE clip_views."viewed_at" = '2015-01-26'
```

to

```
.where(clip_views: {viewed_at: 1.week.ago..Date.today})
# => WHERE clip_views."viewed_at" BETWEEN '2015-01-19 16:45:02.537752' AND '2015-01-26'
```

Instead of looking for views on a certain date, it will search for views from a time range.